# Is there an option to toggle stemming in Solr?

Tags: solr, stemming

I would like to have an option to turn stemming on and off in my searches using some toggling options. How can I do that ?

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

One good option would be to store the value in two fields: one that uses a stemming analyzer and one that does not. You can use the [`<copyField>` element](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) to accomplish this. Your application could then choose which field to use during search.